# Always Null when using the Android Volley

Tags: android, web-services, android-volley

I am new to the android and I created a simple web server with login functionality using PHP. When passing parameters from Android to this server always receiving null.
Below is my code.

My java class to connect to my online server:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private  EditText userNameEd,passwordED;
private  Button   login;
private String LOGIN_URL = "http://404-76-01.com/appLogin.php";
public static String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
public static String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
private String srtUsername,srtPassword;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    userNameEd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    passwordED = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login    = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.signin);

    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           srtUsername = userNameEd.getText().toString();
           srtPassword = passwordED.getText().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "This is my Toast message!"+srtUsername,
                    //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // WebService toLogin = new WebService();
                   // toLogin.login(srtUsername,srtPassword);

            login(srtUsername,srtPassword);
        }
    });
}


public void login(final String username, final String Password){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                   if (response.equals("123")) {
                        callToMenu();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,srtPassword +"/t" +srtUsername ,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                       //Toast.makeText(login, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, srtPassword +"/t" +srtUsername,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //callToMenu();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response.trim() ,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Toast.makeText(this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            }
    ){

        protected Map<String,String> getPaaram() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            map.put(KEY_PASSWORD,Password);
            return map;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}


private  void callToMenu(){
    Intent menu = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Inside.class);
    startActivity(menu);
}
}
```

My PHP code:
When I pass values to this PHP page, $password, and $username always null. I can't find what is wrong with my code.

```
<?php
require_once('Dbconnect.php');
$obj = new Dbconnection();

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];    
$count  = 0;        
$sql = "select * from employee where username = '".$username."' and  PASSWORD  ='".$password."'";    
$result_val = mysqli_query($obj->getdbconnect(),$sql);    
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result_val)){    
        $usname = $rs["username"];
$count++;    
}

var_dump($username,$password);die;
if($count>0){
echo "123";
}else{
echo "fail";
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: replace `Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,new Response.Listener<String>()` with `Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>()Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL, null, new Response.Listener<String>()` and see if you'll get what you want

Comment: you are not passing any parameters to request

Comment: write @Override for getParam method

Comment: @BapusahebShinde i pass the parameter in here .  protected Map<String,String> getPaaram() throws AuthFailureError {

         Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            map.put(KEY_PASSWORD,Password);
            return map;
        }

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this in your code: getParams should be @override anotation

```
  {

               @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
                    map.put(KEY_PASSWORD,Password);
                    return map;
                }
```

Comment: after that is got this error.  "method does not override from Its's superClass"

Comment: check spelling properly..this method should be overriden

Comment: Thanks Mr. Its My spelling mistake.. Again thanks so much

Comment: Wrong, annotations has nothing to do with the byte code. In fact, the 'o' starts with 'O' i.e. capital 0 not the lower case.

Answer (score 1):

Debug your app to ensure you're passing valid values to the network stack.
Use a tool like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to view the outgoing request and validate whether your issue is in the client or the server. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Mr @dominicoder. Its was my spelling mistake